# WORD-VBA: Search for formatted words then show formatting properties

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm new to VBA, I'm trying to search for all the words in a paragraph that has a formatting, then show all the format properties. For example, if the word is bold and italic, I want to show that the specific is bold and italic.

Is there a shorter code or built-in function for this?

Answer (score 0):

```
For Each wrd In ActiveDocument.Words
    If wrd.Italic = True And wrd.Bold = True Then
        MsgBox wrd
    End If
Next wrd
```

Something like this? (This will also show you empty lines, if they are formatted as Bold and Italic)